# Different views in custom adapter in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, baseadapter

I'm new in android..
I would like to create the different views in Listview using Custom Adapter.
Please suggest me how I can do this.

In first row there will be a single Item and in second row there will be two item and so on..

Please Check the attached screen..

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have tried till now.

Comment: @Yugesh I've set the adapter with custom layout.. Its showing one item in row or two in row..

Comment: @Priyank Due to low rating on SO.. Its not allowing me to add Screen

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials online. First check whether there are existing questions that matches your question, and then only ask on stackoverflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Listview with different layout for each row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row)

Comment: @4k3R, try to encorage new comers we are here to teach them if they are new to stackoverflow

Comment: http://kyogs.blogspot.in/2014/06/the-use-of-getviewtypecount-and.html

Comment: @Gopic.s I wasn't trying to be rude. I didn't even vote down. I just want to give a clear idea to the OP, what to do as a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a custom layout of how you want the list row like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="@dimen/headerHeightCustRow"
 android:background="#FFFFFF"
 tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/viewSpace1"
    android:text="Varun Mad"
    android:textSize="@dimen/logout_textSize"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/orange_normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCustId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/viewSpace3"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/viewSpace3"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/viewSpace3"
    android:text="10549"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textColor="@color/orange_normal"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/viewSpace1"
    android:text="(886)677-8855"
    android:textColor="@color/orange_normal"
    android:textSize="@dimen/vsText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/viewSpace1"
    android:text="ggg@gmail.com"
    android:textSize="@dimen/vsText"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtPhone"
    android:textColor="@color/orange_normal" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/greyDark" />
```

here is the adapter class

```
public class SearchCustomerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<SearchCustomerItem> objects;

public SearchCustomerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchCustomerItem> products) {
    ctx = context;
    objects = products;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_cust_row, parent, false);
    }

    SearchCustomerItem p = getProduct(position);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName)).setText(p.customerName);

    if (p.customerEmail.compareTo("anyType{}") == 0) {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail)).setText("");
    } else {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail)).setText(p.customerEmail);
    }
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPhone)).setText(p.customerPhone);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCustId)).setText(p.customerId);

    return view;
}

SearchCustomerItem getProduct(int position) {
    return ((SearchCustomerItem) getItem(position));
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
ArrayList<SearchCustomerItem> getBox() {
    ArrayList<SearchCustomerItem> box = new ArrayList<SearchCustomerItem>();
    for (SearchCustomerItem p : objects) {
      //  if (p.box)
      //      box.add(p);
    }
    return box;
}
```

}

and the ITem Class

```
public class SearchCustomerItem {

public String customerName;
public String customerPhone;
public String customerEmail;
public String customerId;

 public SearchCustomerItem(String _cName, String _cPhone, String _cEmail, String _cCustId) {
     customerName = _cName;
     customerPhone = _cPhone;
     customerEmail = _cEmail;
     customerId = _cCustId;
 }  
}
```

you can initialize the adapter,
add the items in Arraylist and show in the list by using

```
SearchCustomerAdapter boxAdapter;
ArrayList<SearchCustomerItem> products = new ArrayList<SearchCustomerItem>();
```

to add items in arraylist

```
products.add(new SearchCustomerItem("CustomerName","PhoneNo","Cust_EmailId","Cust_Id"));
```

//Add as many items you want

than

```
boxAdapter = new SearchCustomerAdapter(SearchActivity.this, products);
list.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you. [link](http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-listview) 
You should do it step by step.

1. Extend Base Adapter class by you Custom Adapter class
2. Override getView and other related methods
3. set the adapter to list view adapter.